# Activated multisite and added a site, but can't access it

Tags: multisite

I just activated multisite, and added a new site. But when I try to access it, I get this error:

```
ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

Is there something else to do ?

I activated multisite in wp-config, then modified htaccess as shown in the wordpress admin. Then I went to Sites>add site and filled the address and admin email fields.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you please provide some more details. What did you "followed precisely"? What steps did you take? Added a new site where?

Answer (score -2):

Are you doing the sub-sites as a subdomain or sub-directory? If it is a subdomain you will need to register that domain with your hosting provider.

Comment: Why the downvotes?